# Overlaying clear background color on hover (sass)

Tags: css, sass

I have a div with a background image. I want to be able to set a black transparent overlay on hover. How can I achieve this?

This is what I have so far

```
div {
  background: url('map-tracks.png');
  background-size: cover;
  transition: background-color 1s;
  &:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you actually want to see the background image still, use a pseudo element.

```css
div {
  background: url('http://via.placeholder.com/200x200');
  background-size: cover;
  transition: background-color 1s;
  width: 200px; 
  height: 200px;

}

div:hover:after
{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put an overlay (a div or something else) with absolute or relative positioning and with the proper **black-semi transparent** styling. Anyway you need another object for the overlay.